# what does the result of my wifi diagnostic test tell

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, wifi-configuration

what does these mean

```
LAN Connection Check
Test Switch LAN PORT 1  DOWN
Test Switch LAN PORT 2  DOWN
Test Switch LAN PORT 3  DOWN
Test Switch LAN PORT 4  DOWN

WLAN Connection Check
Test WLAN Root AP       UP/LINKED
Test WLAN Virtual AP0   DOWN
Test WLAN Virtual AP1   DOWN
Test WLAN Virtual AP2   DOWN
Test WLAN Virtual AP3   DOWN

ADSL Connection Check
Test ADSL Synchronization           PASS
Test ATM OAM F5 Segment Loopback    PASS
Test ATM OAM F5 End-to-End Loopback PASS
Test ATM OAM F4 Segment Loopback    FAIL
Test ATM OAM F4 End-to-End Loopback FAIL

Internet Connection Check
Test PPP Server Connection              PASS
Test Authentication with ISP            PASS
Test WAN IP Address: 122.167.102.238    PASS
Ping Default Gateway                    PASS
Ping Primary Domain Name Server         FAIL
```

Answer (score 1):

It means that:

1. There are no wired devices plugged in
2. you have one Wifi AP defined, with no virtual APs.
3. your device is able to connect over ADSL and using ATM OAM F5.
4. you are able to connect to your ISP over PPP, login, and get a WAN IP.
5. Your DNS server address is misconfigured. This will only be a problem if you use the device for DNS resolution.

Comment: would fixing dns improve my network speed esp form mobile

Comment: no, probably not. Slow DNS can definitely slow you down, but a slow server would PASS and not show any issues in this particular report. This error indicates that the server is completely down or its configuration is plain wrong.

Comment: this is what i notice when ever my net is unresponsive. I restart router and my net becomes normal for some time . Is it isp 's fault or my routers.

Comment: it is not possible to tell from the info provided. I've generally found that home routers start acting this way when they near end of live, especially if the user is running protocols with many tiny connections (eg Bittorrent), but thats just my experience. its not generally possible to get good diagnostic info from the device when its in such a state.

Comment: if you want to test whether the issue is DNS, set your device to use a publicly accessible DNS server like Googles at 8.8.8.8.

Comment: thanks i will do that and let you know. More over the issue generally more on mobile than desktop. Anything on this ??

Comment: none of this has any relation to desktop vs mobile. The above tests tell you almost nothing about the state of your WiFi (other than that it reports UP), so you may want to run other tests to determine if there is a problem there, but there is no indication of such in the logs you provide. Try setting the mobile device to use 8.8.8.8 as the DNS server.